# I have written the code correctly but the Turtle is not appearing on the screen

Tags: python-turtle

/// This is the code for the turtle game that I have written

## class for creating the  turtle  as player

```
# and it begins mostly from here 

STARTING_POSITION = (0, -280)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
FINISH_LINE_Y = 280


class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('turtle')
        self.color('black')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(STARTING_POSITION)

# main file
import time
from turtle import Screen
from player import Player

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)
screen.exitonclick()
user = Player()
game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()
```

The output that I am getting is:

[image]

Comment: You're defining `Player` and then overriding `Player` with the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you put the line `screen.exitonclick()` in the wrong location in your code.  If used, this should be the *last* thing you do as it turns over control to the tkinter event loop.  Any statements following it are never executed.  However, due to your use of `while True:`, a correctly placed `screen.exitonclick()` will never be reached unless `game_is_on` turns `False` at some point.

```
import time
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

STARTING_POSITION = (0, -280)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
FINISH_LINE_Y = 280

class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('turtle')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(STARTING_POSITION)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

user = Player()

game_is_on = True

while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()

screen.exitonclick()  # never reached
```